# nustache like nuget package for dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, nustache

In asp.net MVC worked with nustache NuGet package which is binding models to HTML

Right now working with Dotnet core 2.1
And can not find nustache is working with the Dotnet core.
So there is an alternative for nustache which can work with Dotnet core 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nustache version 1.16.0.10 works well in project targeting netcoreapp2.2, despite the warnings from compiler

Comment: hello @Vera Pavlovna do you know best free NuGet extension for HTML to pdf generator

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat You can try wkhtmltopdf. It can be suitable for your needs.